# There's a way to pass more Models instance in the authorize method (policy) with the 'create' action (usually is not not required a model instance)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm stuck in a policy problem. Actually I have a **OrderEventHistoryPolicy** and a

```
class OrderEventHistoryPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create the order event history.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Order\Order  $order
     */
    public function create(User $user, OrderEventHistory $orderEventHistory, Order $order)
    }
```

and a **OrderEventHistoryController**

```
class OrderEventHistoryController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Order\Order $order
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Order $order)
    {
        $this->authorize('create',OrderEventHistory::class, $order);
    }
}
```

My aim is to pass the Order model to the policy class (**OrderEventHistoryPolicy**), but according to
Laravel 5.8 documentation, you can just pass the class name with **action** like 'OrderEventHistoryPolicy'. By
passing the class name I am not able to pass the Order model (of course). 
Here's the Laravel documentation:

> As previously discussed, some
>   actions like create may not require a model instance. In these
>   situations, you may pass a class name to the authorize method. The
>   class name will be used to determine which policy to use when
>   authorizing the action:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
   $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
   // The current user can create blog posts... 
}
```

What I was thinking is to pass a empty **OrderEventHistory** model like this:

```
$this->authorize('create',new OrderEventHistory(), $order);
```

But I am not sure this is the "right" and "clean" way for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to `authorize()`:

```php
$this->authorize('create', [new OrderEventHistory(), $order]);
```

The elements of the array will be passed to the policy method as separate parameters, so your policy code is already correct.

Comment: Thankyou @Thomas, if this is the right way i will do it like this :)